# Calculate distance between 2 lat longs

Tags: r, geospatial, geo, haversine

I have 4 columns in my data frame lat1,long1...lat2,long2. I need to calculate distance between these pairs. I am trying to use Distm function.

When I try to use `distm (c(mydata2$lst_upd_longitude,mydata2$lst_upd_latitude), c(mydata2$long,mydata2$lat), fun = distHaversine)`

R throws up an error "Error in .pointsToMatrix(x) : Wrong length for a vector, should be 2"
For now I am using the below code to calculate distance for every point. But I am sure there should be a better solution. Also this code consumes lot of time.

```
for( i in 1:nrow(mydata2)){
  mydata2$distance[i] <- distm (c(mydata2$lst_upd_longitude[i],mydata2$lst_upd_latitude[i]), 
                                c( mydata2$long[i],mydata2$lat[i]), 
                                fun = distHaversine)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
df <- read.table(sep=",", col.names=c("lat1", "lon1", "lat2", "lon2"), text="
52,4,52,13 
39,116,52,13")
library(geosphere)
distHaversine(df[, 2:1], df[, 4:3]) / 1000 # Haversine distance in km
```

Comment: My lat long data is already in data frame. when I apply distm function directly am getting error Error in .pointsToMatrix(x) : Wrong length for a vector, should be 2

Comment: My lat long data is also in a data frame. When a apply distHaverine I get no error, but the distances between the pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below Script Code:

```
 function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
 var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
 var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
 var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
 var a = 
 Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
 Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
 Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
 ; 
 var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
 var d = R * c; // Distance in km
 return d;
 }

function deg2rad(deg) {
 return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

For more details follow the below link:

[Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula?page=1&tab=active#tab-top)